# How to display data in Bootstrap DataTable

Tags: php, wordpress, datatable

```
I want to display data in bootstrap datatable.

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4
```

I have create a code to display the events in list format. Everything is working Fine.But want to show data in Bootstrap Data Table.

```
<?php
// declaring data           
global $post;
$all_events = tribe_get_events(array(
    'eventDisplay' => 'upcoming',
    'tag' => 'swiss',
    'posts_per_page' => 100
        ));
?>
<!-- fetching events based on upcoming and tags. -->
<?php foreach ($all_events as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="col-md-12 event_col">
            <div class="col-md-4"><span>- <?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post->ID, false, 'dS M, Y | h:i a'); ?></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><span><?php echo tribe_get_venue(); ?></span></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </a>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <!-- end .event-wrap -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if-test the events array, if it is empty it is evaluated as false.

```
<?php
if (!$all_events) : ?>
    <div class="..."><span><?php echo "No events found"></span></div>
<?php else:
<?php foreach ($all_events as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    ...
    ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was wrong. Please Check the updated question.